# How many terms are there in expansion of $(x_1 +x_2+\ldots +x_r)^n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, multinomial-theorem

How many terms are there in expansion of

$(a)(x_1 +x_2+\ldots+ x_r)^n$

$(b)(1+x_1+x_2+\ldots+ x_{r-1})^n$

for $(a)$, a term in its expansion will look like $$C\cdot x_{1}^{k_1}\cdot x_2^{k_2}\cdots x_{r}^{k_r}$$

where $k_1 + k_2 +\ldots +k_r = n\;\; \; \;| k_i \geq 0$

So number of terms will be equal to the solutions of above $=C(n+r-1,r-1)$

I think answer for (b) should be same as well?

Comment: please confirm if this is correct

Comment: I don't understand how (b) would be different. The number of terms is the [number of multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_multinomial_coefficients) in a multinomial sum, i.e. $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$, as the OP showed. Why would this change if we set $x_r=1$? Expanding $(x+y+z)^2$ gives $6$ terms, which doesn't change when we set $z=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $(b)$, note that the number of terms equals the number of solutions $(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_{r-1})$ to
$$k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_{r-1}\leq n$$
with each variable being a non-negative integer.  Let $k_r=n-k_1-k_2-\ldots-k_{r-1}$.  Then $(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_r)$ is a non-negative integer solution to
$$k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_r=n.$$
Hence the answers to $(a)$ and $(b)$ are the same.

An alternative way to see this is to observe that
$$\left(1+y_1+y_2+\ldots+y_{r-1}\right)^n=\frac{(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_r)^n}{x_r^n},$$
where $y_i=\frac{x_i}{x_r}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,r-1$.

Comment: $1^2x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}$ and $1^3x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}$ are not distinct terms in (b). This means that there are fewer terms in (b) than there are in (a)

Comment: @DanielMathias  But at most one of them can occur as an expansion of $(b)$ simply because $2+k_1+k_2\neq 3+k_1+k_2$.  And perhaps you should try to do the expansion to test your theory for small $n$ and $r$ to see that the answers to $(a)$ and $(b)$ are equal in these case.

Comment: Indeed, $(x+y+z)^3$ and $(x+y+1)^3$ each have ten terms.

Comment: @DanielMathias this can be seen by treating it with associativity of addition, then as a binomial:$$(x+(y+z))^3$$$$=x^3+3x^2(y+z)+3x(y+z)^2+(y+z)^3$$$$=x^3+3x^2y+3x^2z+3xy^2+6xyz+3xz^2+y^3+3y^2z+3yz^2+z^3$$